# List child pages of the current page's parent

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm developing a WordPress theme using version 3.5.1, and in every page I want to display a side vertical menu displaying all the pages that belong to the current's page parent.
I've tried with this:

```
<?php
    $args = array( 
        'sort_column' => 'menu_order',
        'child_of' => $post->parent
    );
?>
<ul>
    <?php wp_list_pages($args);  ?>
</ul>
```

But what I get listed is every parent page, instead of what I pretend to do.
What is the best approach to do this?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a syntax error.

Try this: `'child_of' => $post->post_parent`

That should return the siblings of the page you're in.

Comment: Yes! I had a typo there... Thank you very much!